# PHP variable in div class

Tags: php, html, css, variables, if-statement

I just want to know if it is possible to do something like this:

```
<?php
   if(condition1 > condition2){
       $variable = "class1";
   }else{
       $variable = "class2";
   }
?>
<div class=$variable></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it possible. But for that you need to learn how PHP syntax works.

Comment: YES: `<?php $variable = (condition1 > condition2)?"class1":"class2"; ?>` same as in javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use it like

```
    <?php
      if(condition1 > condition2){
      $variable = "class1";
      }else{
      $variable = "class2";
      }
     ?>

    <div class="<?php echo $variable; ?>" ></div>
```

Comment: @user3443985 Welcome you

Answer (score 2):

You can use short php open+echo tags:

```
<?php
   if(condition1 > condition2){
       $variable = "class1";
   }else{
       $variable = "class2";
   }
?>
<div class=<?=$variable;?>></div>
```

These are permanently enabled as of php5.4: http://www.php.net//manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

> `<?=` is now always available, regardless of the `short_open_tag php.ini` option.

---

Make sure your HTML output is valid and standard. If `$variable` contains a space or html special characters you may run into issues:

```
<div class="<?=htmlspecialchars($variable);?>"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

of course it is

```
<div class="<?php echo $variable; ?>"></div>
```

cheers.

Comment: You are forgetting something.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing right just write

```
<div class="<?php echo $variable; ?>" ></div>
```